# How to generate an assert that forces a false?

Tags: prolog, prolog-assert

First of all thanks for your help.

On to my problem: Let's say I have:

```
some_fact:- true.
```

and I want to asserta a rule on top of it that looks like this:

```
some_fact:- fail, !.
```

This is because I want to transform the "`some_fact:- true.`" to force a false without removing the rule (I don't want to use `abolish(some_fact,0).` )

The problem is that I can't find the way to do it because I can't place the comma on the asserta/1. What I mean is that when I put:

```
asserta(some_fact:- fail, !).
```

the comma in between forces a call to asserta/2 instead of asserta/1 with the whole rule, and I cannot prevent that using quotes because it asserts a string.

Of course I can't just simply put `asserta(some_fact:- fail).` because prolog will search for the next some_fact which returns true.

Any ideas? Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just add parenthesis:

```
?- asserta((some_fact:- fail, !)).
true.
```

Comment: Jesus I can't believe that it was that simple. I couldn't find it anywhere. Thanks!!

Comment: that'll work better if it's   asserta((some_fact:- !, fail)).

Answer (score 1):

To assert the fact:

`asserta(zoo(zebra)).`

When the fact is no longer true:

`retract(zoo(zebra)).`

More general:

```
asserting(Fact) :-
    asserta(Fact).

retracting(Fact) :-
    retract(Fact).
```

Example:

```
?- asserting(zoo(zebra)).
true.

?- zoo(zebra).
true.

?- retracting(zoo(zebra)).
true.

?- zoo(zebra).
false.
```

Comment: I already said that I didn't want to do abolish (retract does not work btw because it's a rule with arity 0, not a fact). Thanks anyway.

Comment: It seemed you were asking about a fact because you consistently used the name 'some_fact' in your question. Regardless, it does work with rules with arity 0. Have you tried out my example? Also, like mbratch I don't understand why you are trying to avoid removing the rule. Can you explain?

Comment: Yeah... I should've used "some_rule:- true". Sorry haha. I'm not trying to avoid removing the rule actually, I just wanted to know how to assert that due to a more complicated scenario which I simplified here. Thanks!

Comment: Oh and for some reason my teacher said the same thing: that retract works for rules with arity 0. However, when we both tried it on the program it didn't work! So we used abolish instead. Thanks a ton mate!

Comment: Cheers for the reply! By the way: if the predicate is already in use and you want to assert/retract you have to declare it as 'dynamic' first. So that could be a reason for it not working.